# Super-hero PHP code refactoring: How to initialize variables

Tags: php

I need to run over some pages written in PHP by somebody that doesn't know that a variable should be initialized before use..

Therefore I have thousands of lines to check in order to make sure I Do not have such thing

```
<?php
    $foo = $bar . "I m a noob"; 
?>
```

and of course having the problem with *$bar* not initialized. 
The problem is that I have about 20~50 variables in this case in 25 files..

Do you know any **super-hero way** to set all the variables to ' ' or null ? 
I do not want to set the warning level to E or W .. that's too crappy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There’s no super-human way I’m aware of. Just keep an eye on your **error_log** file warnings about undefined variables and fix them as you come across them, and make sure any variables are defined before used in code you write in the future.

Comment: Yes Martin, that's a way but It took me already 30 min just for 4 pages -_- still have 20 to go ..

Comment: You should be done in two-and-a-half hours at that rate then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically this code at the beginning of the script does the job:

```
$code = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
preg_match_all('/(?<=\$)[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/', $code, $matches);
$variables = array_unique($matches[0]);
foreach ($variables as $variable) {
    if (!isset($$variable)) {
        $$variable = null;
    }
}
```

The regular expression is from [PHP site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

**EDIT**

A clean and quicker way, without a regular expression:

```
$code = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
$tokens = token_get_all($code);
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if (is_array($token) && $token[0] == T_VARIABLE) {
        $variable = ltrim($token[1], '$');
        if (!isset($$variable)) {
            $$variable = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's official you are my super-hero of the day! the others please vote for this guy it save me quite some time. thanxx @edakos.

Answer (score -3):

you can use an array for the 25:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) { $bar[$i] = ''; /* you can change the "" to null */ }
```

using an array with a for, you can set a great number of vars with diferente values, or with the same value.

Comment: This is not possible, $bar is not an array but a variable.and even $bar was an array the following piece of code do only work if the index is an integer...